# Regex to extract dates after some specified words

Tags: python, regex

i would like to extract the date of birth from these text. there are four conditions:

```
keywords to match 

    Date of Birth 
    date of birth:
    D.O.B:
    DOB:
```

The strings like that:

```
text = "my name is adam my DOB: 30-11-1988 and i play football since 20-2011"
text = "my name is D.O.B: 20/MAY/1987 and i play football since 20-2011"
text = "my Date of Birth 12-7-1970 and i start study since 20-2011"
text = "my date of birth: 20/9/1970 "
```

Comment: In [SO], you are supposed to show any code that you've tried with, which makes sure that you've tried with something to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
regex = r'(Date of Birth|date of birth|D.O.B|DOB):\s(\S*)'
```

Your Group 2 will contain the Captured date in any format.

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/gDNK0o/1/)

**Explanation**

- **`(Date of Birth|date of birth|D.O.B|DOB)`**: Look for any of the alternatives of the dob phrases.
- **`:\s`** : look for a colon followed by space character.
- **`(\S*)`**: look for any no. of continuous non space characters, which is the date you want.

Comment: The OP tagged python, not javascript

Comment: this is for python not javascript

Comment: You said earlier _this is for python_, but now where has your `/g` (which is the global flag in JS) and other JS regex stuff gone?

Comment: that was just a non language specific regex to show the use of global flag, attached demo link still had the python demo. I added `r''` for more clarity after your comment. btw `/g` is in many other languages as well and not just JS

Comment: Yeah, now it should work. BTW, does _a non language specific regex_ include the `/g` flag?

Comment: i just wrote a quick regex, `/g` was to show the use of global flag, and was further going to update the answer. Anyways, thanks for the suggestion @Sнаđошƒаӽ

Comment: Okay, one not familiar with JS regex syntax won't know that it means global, and won't be able to tell that `/g` apart from actual the regex to use, right? Anyway, I had to do something, so I did. Peace! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
(DOB: \d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,4}|D.O.B: \d{1,2}\/[A-Z]{1,}\/\d{1,4}|Date of Birth \d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,4}|date of birth: \d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,4})
```

- \d : represents all digits i.e. [0-9]
- {1,2} : length i.e. minimum 1    or maximum 2 characters
- [A-Z] : allow A-Z all alphabets

I hope it works for you

Comment: No it won't work for OP, because OP just wants the date after the specified _key words_.

Comment: Oops, now I see it is not even valid regex for dates.

Comment: Can you check again, now I have included valid strings as well.

Comment: It is still incomplete, and to complete it in the way you are going, I am afraid it is going to be one hell of long regex.